# How to reuse or call function in angular from a seperate file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function which is a converter . The code is in file1.ts but I wanted to reuse it on file2.ts . Any idea  ?thanks

#Code

```
 formatBytes(bytes, decimals = 2) : string | number {
    console.log("lol")
    if (bytes === 0) {
      return '0 Bytes';
    }

    const k = 1024;
    const dm = decimals < 0 ? 0 : decimals;
    const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];

    const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));

    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two options here :

1. You can create utility.ts and keep the function there.
2. Place the function is some common service and inject that service to use it.

> I would recommend to create a utility.ts file and keep adding the
> function which are being used commonly across files.

There could other ways too.

Comment: it is not a good idea to use the same function on the 2 files right ? so its necessary to create a service for it

Comment: Yes it is redudant code , until and unless you are doing something different in both files. Either create a utility file or common service.

Comment: how about an angular Pipe ?

Comment: If you want to directly use it in HTML , go for it.

Comment: I would prefer creating a service for it